# Swift 4 JSONDecoder optional variable

Tags: swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I have a `Codable` struct `myObj`:

```
public struct VIO: Codable {

    let id:Int?;
    ...
    var par1:Bool = false; //default to avoid error in parsing
    var par2:Bool = false;    
}
```

When I do receive JSON, I don't have `par1` and `par2` since these variables are optional. During parsing I get an error:`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: \"par1\", intValue: nil)`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have local variables you have to specify the `CodingKeys`

```
public struct VIO: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id }

    let id:Int?
    ...
    var par1:Bool = false
    var par2:Bool = false  

}
```

Edit:

If `par1` and `par2` should be also decoded optionally you have to write a custom initializer

```
  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id, par1, par2 }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
      par1 = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .par1)
      par2 = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .par2)
  }
```

This is Swift: **No trailing semicolons**

Comment: so in my case I need to simply include `private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case par1 = false case par2 = false }` ?

Comment: @AlexP No... what he showed *is your case.* The coding keys are usually inferred from the type's property names. Specifying the coding keys explicitly gives you a chance to omit `par1`, and `par2`, and just have `id`.

Comment: this means  in CodingKeys I shall put all variables that I am sure are present in JSON?

Comment: You need to specify only the CodingKeys you want to decode.

Comment: I have a problem: now these values are never parsed even if present

Comment: @AlexP Which values?

Comment: `par1` and `par2` , those that were not in CodingKeys. I always get them as `false`

Comment: You wrote: *these variables are used only locally.*

Comment: Yeah you are right, I didn't consider one use-case. I parse everything to json and then retrieve. So they are really optional in both directions, but should be parsed as well

Comment: Then write a custom initializer and use `decodeIfPresent`

Comment: could you please make an example as an answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last question it works for both decoder and encoder or for encoder I need another init()?